# How to strip tags in PHP using regex?

Tags: php, regex, strip-tags

```
$string = 'text <span style="color:#f09;">text</span>
<span class="data" data-url="http://www.google.com">google.com</span>
text <span class="data" data-url="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo.com</span> text.';
```

What I want to do is get the **data-url** from all spans with the class **data**. So, it should output:

```
$string = 'text <span style="color:#f09;">text</span>
http://www.google.com text http://www.yahoo.com text.';
```

And then I want to remove all the remaining **html tags**.

```
$string = strip_tags($string);
```

Output:

```
$string = 'text text http://www.google.com text http://www.yahoo.com text.';
```

Can someone please tell me how this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your string contains more than just the HTML snippet you show, you should use [DOM](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) with this [XPath](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

```
//span/@data-url
```

Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach( $xp->query('//span/@data-url') as $node ) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

The above would output

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
```

When you already have the HTML loaded, you can also do

```
echo $dom->documentElement->textContent;
```

which returns the same result as `strip_tags($string)` in this case:

```
text text
google.com
text yahoo.com text.
```

Comment: There is no text node within an attribute value. This should be `//span/@data-url`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `SimpleXML` and foreach by the elements - then check if `class` attribute is valid and grab the `data-url`'s

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/data/" data-url=/"([^']*)/i", $string , $urls);
```

You can fetch all URls a=by this way.

And you can also use simplexml as *hsz* mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: don't.  There's a lovely rant somewhere around SO explaining why parsing html with regexes is a bad idea.  Essentially it boils down to 'html is not a regular language so regular expressions are not adequate to parse it'. What you need is something DOM aware.

As @hsz said, SimpleXML is a good option if you know that your html validates as XML. Better might be [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) which doesn't require well-formed html. Once your html is in a DOMDocument object then you can extract what you will very easily. Check out the docs [here](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).